# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when running trying to open android emulator with appium

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, appium

I am trying to run the following code from Windows in Eclipse and finding the error that I've mentioned in the Title. Can anybody please suggest me.

**Code:**

```
package com.apanp.one;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;    
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;    
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        File  f = new File("src");
        File fs =new File(f,"original.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Shayan");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver <> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1/wd/hub"), cap);    
    }   
}
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
>    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>    at com.apanp.one.base.main(base.java:24)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>    ... 10 more
> ```

[AVDManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw8Ww.png)

[image: Virtual Device Manage]

**Config:**

1. JDK 
   JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
   Java bin: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin
2. ANDROID STUDIO DOWNLOAD:https://developer.android.com/studio
   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
   ANDROID-TOOLS-PATH:C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
   ANDROID-TOOLS-BIN PATH: C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
   ANDROID-PLATFORM-PATH:C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
3. CREATE ANDROID EMULATOR IN AVD MANAGER
4. WE CAN INVOKE EMULATOR THROUGH COMMAND PROMPT:C:\Users\Shahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
   THEN TYPE:emulator -avd Shayan
5. INSTALL node.js:https://nodejs.org/en/download/
6. NODE_HOME:C:\Program Files\nodejs
7. NPM_HOME:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
8. INSTALL APPIUM SERVER(using npm through command prompt): npm install -g appium
9. SOME COMMANDS WITH APPIUM SERVER: 
       -to start appium server: appium
       -to close appium server: ctrl + C; Y/N-> y and ENTER
               -to check version:appium --version
               -to check where it is: where appium
10. INSTALL APPIUM JAVA CLIENT LIBRARY:http://appium.io/downloads.html; SELECT JAVA; SELECT JAR
11. DOWNLOAD ECLIPSE:https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

Answer (score 0):

**ClassNotFoundException** means you don’t have any class in your `classpath` to address this  **com/google/common/base/Function** that means you are missing this class which belongs to **guava** dependency/jar in your project. Please add below dependency if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>23.6-jre</version>

  <!-- or, for Android: -->
  <version>23.6-android</version>
</dependency>
```

**For java:**

You can download jar file and keep it on class path